# Explanation needed, why adding implements Serializable to Singleton class is insufficient?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me what is this means? especially the bold lines.

> To make a singleton class serializable, **it is not sufficient merely
>   to add `implements Serializable` to its declaration**. To maintain the
>   singleton guarantee, you have to declare all instance fields
>   `transient` and provide a `readResolve()` method. Otherwise, **each
>   time a serialized instance is deserialized, a new instance will be
>   created**, leading, in the case of our example, to spurious Elvis
>   sightings. To prevent this, add this `readResolve()` method to the
>   `Elvis` class:
>
> ```
> // Singleton with static factory
> public class Elvis {
>     private static final Elvis INSTANCE = new Elvis();
>     private Elvis() { ... }
>     public static Elvis getInstance() { return INSTANCE; }
>     public void leaveTheBuilding() { ... }
> }
>
> // readResolve method to preserve singleton property
> private Object readResolve() {
>     // Return the one true Elvis and let the garbage collector
>     // take care of the Elvis impersonator.
>     return INSTANCE;
> }
> ```

FYI: these lines are from Effective Java Book, Item 3

Comment: I think the quoted lines explain it pretty well, no? Deserialization bypasses the normal class constructor to construct an instance -- so even though the constructor is private, I can end up with two separate Elvises by calling `getInstance()`, and then serializing and deserializing it.

Comment: I don't see why JB considers declaring the instance fields transient necessary. A readResolve() method should be enough. Making the fields transient defeats the whole purpose as far as I can see.

Comment: @TomG then how readResolve() method will solve this issue?

Comment: @NarendraPathai Explained how?

Comment: @kuredi The code of the readResolve() method you've posted is self-explanatory. readResolve() is invoked by readObject() and has the option of retuning an alternate object instead of 'this'. The result is that readObject() will always return INSTANCE, not what's in the stream.

Comment: @EJP The reason is explained by Josh Bloch himself here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi_I7oD_uGI#t=1733 (or in the Effective Java 2nd edition, item 77). Because of this, I try to use `enum` singletons as much as I can.

Comment: @Slanec I don't have the book, and the YouTube video is just a lot of handwaving that refers to the book for details of the 'cleverly crafted attack'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have two classes that have a reference to the instance `SingletonClass`

```
public class ClassA implements Serializable {

    private SingletonClass s = SingletonClass.getInstance();

}


public class ClassB implements Serializable {

    private SingletonClass s = SingletonClass.getInstance();

}
```

If instances of `ClassA` and `ClassB` are each serialized and then deserialized, they have will both be creating new instances of `SingletonClass` because it's not being retrieved through the `getInstance` method, but rather it's being deserialized from some persistent storage.

By modifying the singleton class as you did, when you deserialize it, it will always return the static shared instance, so each deserialization will reference `INSTANCE`

Comment: Would you please explain more how readResolve() method will solve this issue?

Comment: Because the `INSTANCE` in `SingletonClass` is initialized once when the class is loaded. All deserialized versions will then reference that same `INSTANCE` rather than deserializing their own version of it.

Comment: Lets say the private constructor of SingletonClass has print "hello", if we deserialize both ClassA and ClassB, will "Hello" be printed twice?

Comment: No, deserialization doesn't call the constructor.

Comment: OK, now its clearer, one last thing i need to know, how can I tell that there are two instances of the SingletonClass?

Comment: Best way would be to use a profiler like VisualVM. If you want to know in code if instances are the same references, compare them with `==`

Answer (score 4):

The `readResolve` method is called when `ObjectInputStream` has read an object from the stream and is preparing to return it to the caller. `ObjectInputStream` checks whether the class of the object defines the `readResolve` method. If the method is defined, the `readResolve` method is called to allow the object in the stream to designate the object to be returned.

And in Singleton case we are returning the same instance that was created while classloading and no new instances are returned. So singletonness is maintained.